# Как экранировать html теги в телеграм боте aiogram

Tags: python, html, telegram-bot, aiogram

Всем здравствуйте, пишу чат-ботов для Telegram на языке Python и библиотеке aiogram версии 2.х

Ищу способ как можно экранировать `html` теги при отправке сообщений с `parse_mode='HTML'`

Пример: `first_name` пользователя равен **<Степан777>**. При попытке сделать `await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет <b>{message.from_user.first_name}</b>', parse_mode='HTML')` Бот выдаст ошибку `CantParseEntities`

Подскажите пожалуйста кто знает как экранировать html теги

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.escape

Comment: Спасибо, помогло